# JQuery AJAX call: 304 respose produces an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-304

I have a script on localhost that sends a GET request to the same domain. It results in 304 response, which apparently JQuery treats as an error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/file.js',
        error: function(e) {
            console.log('error: ' + e.responseText); // I see this message in console
        },
        success: function(e) {
            console.log('success: ' + e.responseText); // I don't see this message in console
        }
    });
});
```

1) Why do I get a 304 response?
2) How can I modify the code so that the success function gets called? (instead of error function)

Comment: My guess is the error stems from you receiving a .js file, jQuery is expecting json

Comment: No problem, added it

Comment: for future reference, 304 is not an error but a server response saying the file hasn't changed it is cached. jQuery SHOULD handle this correctly, but it might not be. Another solution is to add `cache: false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the error stems from you receiving a .js file, jQuery is expecting json

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading a js file, add **dataType: "script"** to your ajax to force it expect js

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work for me.:( Still the same error.